# KOMA toc equal numsep with exact indentation

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, indentation, tocbasic

I'm trying to format the `toc`, but I stuggle with the horizontal spacing and indentation.

1. The chapter and part headings should have a minimum `numsep` of `1em` for the longest number while also being equal for all other numbers.
2. When using `dynnumwidth` to achive equal seperation for all `toc` levels, the indentation of `sections` and `subsections` is different. They should be flush with the heading of the level above, but adjusting them manually does not give exact results.
3. Is there a way to adjust the distance *after* a `part` heading?

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, numbers=noenddot, listof=totoc, toc=indentunnumbered]{scrbook}
\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry} 

\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\scshape\roman{part}}

\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\normalfont\lsstyle\scshape}
\addtokomafont{partentry}{\normalsize\normalfont\lsstyle\scshape}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[raggedpagenumber=true, linefill=\qquad, pagenumberbox=\mbox]{tocline}{part, chapter, section, subsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=1em plus 1pt]{tocline}{part}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[numsep=1em, dynnumwidth]{tocline}{part, chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[dynnumwidth, numsep=1em, indent=2em]{tocline}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[dynnumwidth, numsep=1em]{tocline}{subsection}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{test}
\part{test}
\chapter{test}
    \section{Test}
        \subsection{Test}
\part{test}
\part{test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KOMA-Script documentation explains:

> If [`dynnumwidth`] is active with the `tocline` style, the `numwidth` attribute speciﬁes a minimum value. If a previous LaTeX run has determined that the maximum width of the entry numbers of the same level plus the value of `numsep` is greater than this minimum, the calculated value will be used instead.

That is, if any number of a level exceeds the given `numwidth`, then the actual width of the longest number is used instead. This will necessarily break alignment with the next sectioning level. In order to achieve alignment, you have to choose `numwidth` sufficiently large. In order for the alignment to work out, you will of course have to adjust `indent` as well.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, numbers=noenddot, listof=totoc, toc=indentunnumbered]{scrbook}

\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry} 

\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\scshape\roman{part}}

\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\normalfont\lsstyle\scshape}
\addtokomafont{partentry}{\normalsize\normalfont\lsstyle\scshape}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  raggedpagenumber=true,
  linefill=\qquad,
  pagenumberbox=\mbox,
%  dynnumwidth,
  numsep=1em,
  ]{tocline}{part, chapter, section, subsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=1em plus 1pt]{tocline}{part}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[numwidth=2.5em]{tocline}{part, chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[indent=2.5em, numwidth=3em]{tocline}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[indent=5.5em, numwidth=3.5em]{tocline}{subsection}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{test}

\part{test}

\chapter{test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}

\part{test}

\part{test}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

This does of course mean that you don't actually make use of the `dynnumwidth` functionality at all (except for recognizing if you have to increase the value of `numwidth`), so it may be easier to not use it. In any case, you will have to do a visual check of the table of contents to check if you need to adjust this value (and the `indent` values accordingly). In my opinion, it is better to maybe have a separation of slightly less than 1 em than to have the different levels be just out of alignment and not notice it.

Answer (score 2):

KOMA-Script version 3.31 has introduced attribute `dynindent` for entry style `tocline`. If `dynindent` is enabled, attribute `indent` specifies the minimum indentation of the entries. If the sum of the number width and the indentation of the levels specified by `indentfollows` is larger, then this sum is used as indentation. By default `indentfollows=section` is set for `subsection` and `indentfollows=subsection` is set for `subsubsection`. With KOMA-Script classes additionally `indentfollows=chapter` is set for `section`.

Therefore you can use

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, oneside, numbers=noenddot, listof=totoc, toc=indentunnumbered]{scrbook}[2020/07/22]% needs version 3.31 or newer
\usepackage[osf]{newpxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\scshape\roman{part}}

\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\normalfont\lsstyle\scshape}
\addtokomafont{partentry}{\normalsize\normalfont\lsstyle\scshape}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
   raggedpagenumber=true,
   linefill=\qquad,
   pagenumberbox=\mbox,
   numsep=1em
]{tocline}{part,chapter, section, subsection}% settings for all entry levels
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[beforeskip=1em plus 1pt]{tocline}{part}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[numwidth=2.1em]{tocline}{part,chapter}% adjust numwidth for chapter and part manually
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[dynnumwidth,dynindent]{tocline}{section,subsection}% adjust numwidth and indent automatically

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{test}
\part{test}
\chapter{test}
  \section{Test}
    \subsection{Test}
\part{test}
\part{test}
\end{document}
```

You still have to adjust `numwidth` for `part` and `chapter` manually, if their values should be the same.

Run three times to get

[image]

Regarding 3.: Below a part entry (or other TOC entries) there is no additional vertical space inserted. Therefore the vertical distance after a part entry can not be changed.